# Dynamic Tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, html-table

The following code works fine and it gives the required output:

```
<a target="_blank" href="' . $property_post_link . '" style="color:#f8953a;font-size:18px;margin-left:0px;text-decoration:none"><b>' . $property_name . '</b></a>
<div style="color:#f8953a;font-style:italic">
<!--- <span style="font-weight:bold;">Transaction Type: </span>' . $transaction_type . '  --->
<!--- <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;">Category: </span>' . $newprop_category . ' --->
</div>
<div style="color:#f8953a;font-style:italic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Property Type: </span>' . $proper_type . '
    <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;">BHK: </span>' . $bhk . '
    <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;">Status: </span>' . $status . '
</div>
<div style="color:#f8953a;font-style:italic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Location: </span>' . $loc . '
    <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;">Building Name: </span>' . $buildingname . '
    <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;">No. of Floor: </span>' . $no_floor . '
</div>
<div style="color:#f8953a;font-style:italic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Carpet Area: </span>' . $carpet_area . '
    <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:5px;">Built up Area: </span>' . $buildup_area . '
    <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;">Price: </span>' . $price_options_select . '
</div>
<div style="color:#f8953a;font-style:italic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Contact Person: </span>' . $contactperson . '
</div>
```

But I need to get this in a table. I am using the following code:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr><th>Building</th><th>Location</th><th>BHKs</th><th>Built up Area</th><th>Furnishing</th><th>Quote</th><th>Advance Rent</th><th>Deposit</th><th>Parking</th></tr>";
foreach ($the_rows as $the_row) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $the_row->buildingname . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->loc . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->bhk . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->buildup_area . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->interior_options_select . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->price . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->advrent . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->deposit . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $the_row->car_parking . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

But this is not fetching the results from the database. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is `$the_rows` defined?

Comment: to get the data in rows as per the columns

Comment: Right. But where do you do `$the_rows = <database query code here>`?

Comment: I'm not that good with database query. Can you please explain what are the steps that I need to take?

Comment: This site is more for questions about errors/problems you're running into and less a tutorial " show me the code" site. You might want to start with an online tutorial somewhere. Just search for "php sql query tutorial" and probably "how to set up a sql database locally" Make sure the tutorial was posted within the last year for best results

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple mysql_query() and mysql_fetch_array() then use code below.

```
echo "<table border='1'> 
 <tr><th>Building</th><th>Location</th><th>BHKs</th><th>Built up Area</th><th>Furnishing</th><th>Quote</th><th>Advance Rent</th><th>Deposit</th>       <th>Parking</th></tr>";
foreach ($the_rows as $the_row) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $the_row['buildingname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['loc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['bhk'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['buildup_area'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['interior_options_select'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['price']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['advrent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['deposit'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $the_row['car_parking'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

if not than please deiscribe you database code too,